# Gradle: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Решил перейти с Android Studio 2.3.3 на 3.0-beta-6

При сборке абсолютно любого проекта, будь то Hello World, или "большое"  приложение, возникает такая ошибка:

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

и в дальнейшем совет посмотреть консоль для деталей. Содержимое Gradle Console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResourcesExecuting tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
```

Т.е. вообще ничего интересного. В логе студии вообще какая-то каша:

```
2017-09-18 21:31:32,764 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,047 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-171.4333198, 14 Sep 2017 02:50) 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,048 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86) 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,048 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_91-b15 (Oracle Corporation) 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,048 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.91-b15 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,450 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview3.0 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\>;L7>20B5;L\java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\>;L7>20B5;L\java_error_in_studio.hprof 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,452 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ext: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext: [access-bridge.jar, cldrdata.jar, dnsns.jar, jaccess.jar, jfxrt.jar, localedata.jar, meta-index, nashorn.jar, sunec.jar, sunjce_provider.jar, sunmscapi.jar, sunpkcs11.jar, zipfs.jar] 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,453 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNU charset: Cp1251 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,736 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (32-bit) loaded in 258 ms 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,831 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2017-09-18 21:31:33,857 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2017-09-18 21:32:21,846 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl initialized in 2483 ms 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,072 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.vfs.persistent.FSRecords - Marking VFS as corrupted: 'C:\Users\Пользователь\.AndroidStudioPreview3.0\system\caches\names.dat' does not exist 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,079 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=735 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,269 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl initialized in 509 ms 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,437 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Preview\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,618 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,619 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemImpl initialized in 859 ms 
2017-09-18 21:32:23,650 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.vfs.PlatformVirtualFileManager initialized in 907 ms 
2017-09-18 21:33:05,342 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.KeymapManagerImpl initialized in 260 ms 
2017-09-18 21:33:08,382 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl initialized in 3300 ms 
2017-09-18 21:33:08,485 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.WindowManagerImpl initialized in 3405 ms 
2017-09-18 21:33:10,180 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl initialized in 28 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,092 [8.0_91-b15]   WARN - redentialStore.CredentialStore - User cancelled master password dialog, will be recreated 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,128 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState - Registry values changed by user: 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,128 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryState -   search.everywhere.settings = true 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,141 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ide.FrameStateManagerImpl initialized in 12 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,153 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.notification.impl.NotificationsManagerImpl initialized in 11 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,658 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent initialized in 452 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,783 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.internal.statistic.updater.SendStatisticsComponent initialized in 654 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:49,826 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.configurationStore.StoreAwareProjectManager initialized in 41 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,307 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl initialized in 2480 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,354 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl initialized in 45 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,463 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl initialized in 108 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,547 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - local history version mismatch (was: 0, expected: 6), rebuilding... 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,547 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - .history.utils.LocalHistoryLog - FS has been rebuild, rebuilding local history... 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,616 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.history.integration.LocalHistoryImpl initialized in 152 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:52,684 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.UndoManagerImpl initialized in 67 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:53,288 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.LafManagerImpl initialized in 601 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:53,344 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher initialized in 56 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:53,403 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader initialized in 58 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:53,603 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.ApplicationStatisticsPersistenceComponent initialized in 199 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:53,628 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.notification.EventLog initialized in 24 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:54,116 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.util.net.HttpConfigurable initialized in 487 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:56,145 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2017-09-18 21:36:56,149 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.util.net.ssl.CertificateManager initialized in 2031 ms 
2017-09-18 21:36:58,957 [d thread 1]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.ModifierKeyDoubleClickHandler initialized in 68 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,229 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - tellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor - issue detected: outdated.jvm.version.message2 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,234 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor initialized in 19084 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,264 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager initialized in 24 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,466 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ide.IdeTooltipManager initialized in 189 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,635 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.ide.SaveAndSyncHandlerImpl initialized in 168 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:15,819 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: eap 
2017-09-18 21:37:16,088 [d thread 2]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2017-09-18 21:37:16,429 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent initialized in 791 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:16,447 [8.0_91-b15]   INFO - ij.components.ComponentManager - com.intellij.formatting.FormatterImpl initialized in 16 ms 
2017-09-18 21:37:20,283 [8.0_91-b15]  ERROR - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - com/intellij/util/indexing/IndexId 
com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: com/intellij/util/indexing/IndexId
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getExtension(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensions(ExtensionPointImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initComponent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:473)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/indexing/IndexId
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:210)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructors(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getSortedMatchingConstructors(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:138)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:92)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:77)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexId PluginClassLoader[com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown, 2.3.8]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/indexing/IndexId
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:210)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructors(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getSortedMatchingConstructors(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:138)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:92)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getExtension(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:246)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensions(ExtensionPointImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.getExtensions(Extensions.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initComponent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:473)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexId PluginClassLoader[com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown, 2.3.8]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 47 more
```

На английском SO видел решения связанные с Gradle Vm Options, но я такого пункта в насройках не нашел.

На всякий случай, вот build.gradle модуля app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.SnowVolf.as30"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

build.gradle проекта:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Тесты вам наверняка не нужны. Попробуйте удалить строку с testInstrumentationRunner. Также пакет не должен заглавных букв иметь. Может в этом беда. Исправьте applicationId

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению, ничего не изменилось. Удалил всё что связано с тестами, убрал заглавные буквы в applicationId, но ошибка осталась. Добавил флаг --stacktrace, но консоль всё так же не даёт ничего вразумительного.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё флаг `--debug` добавить. Также не исключено, что гугл добавил вас по месту жительства в бан. В этом случае могут прокси всякие помочь. В теории такое может в Крыму произойти. Точно видел проблему с этим при попытке сборки с либой от VK на Украине.

Comment: Также попробуйте `Fire->Invalidate cache and restart`

Answer (score 1):

Возникла у меня такая ошибка. С большой долей вероятности могу сказать, что это нехватка ОЗУ. В моем случае я просто закрыл Хром, который забирал 1Гб памяти, но правда перед этим удалил все в папках buld и app/buld.
После этого AS "упала" и пришлось снять задачу "OpenJDK", после чего apk был собран успешно.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ошибка "Error during Sync: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение" возникла при установке apk на устройство. Решил заменой дата-кабеля.