# Gradle Sync Issues В соединение отказано

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Новая система чистая Ubuntu 19.10 два раза переустановил
Android Studio 3.5.3 (на Android Studio 3.5.2(тоже самое))
создал default проект из шаблоном (Empty Activity)
ни чего не добавлял , ни чего не удалял .
прокси не использую, firewall не установлен
при Sync Project with Gradle Files выдает ошибку

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:695)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:302)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1634)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1606)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:45)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.execute(CompositeBuildClassPathInitializer.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:80)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:204)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:66)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.execute(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:63)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor$1.run(BuildScriptProcessor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:106)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:483)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:419)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveArtifact$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:183)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:183)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$DownloadArtifactFile.run(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:146)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.access$1500(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ParentPreservingQueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:444)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.access$600(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable$1.create(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:203)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:177)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:476)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/dce7e66b32456a1b1198da0caff3a8acb71548658391e798c79369241e6490a4?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvZGNlN2U2NmIzMjQ1NmExYjExOThkYTBjYWZmM2E4YWNiNzE1NDg2NTgzOTFlNzk4Yzc5MzY5MjQxZTY0OTBhND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnByb3RvYnVmLWphdmEtMy40LjAuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNTc4NDUyMjcwfSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=CTRszy-479aqHkKOHPNIdaiMtQRoJv6JywUKg1quqwdRvwT-rQVg79xQDA-KU735CyUDLfw17-RoxtUgXv~I833sKEI3KstaQ9ed54zR056z2jwnD~G659S3THsseZXmxWK~a6~13M4MEd9dB8WqNJWL-tuBUJSTVV8X3-bvDGKHMs02u1xk1S8SHnRjk2oGcvSCUZXRSGvR0Dzn-bWK3ze4mOnaxo9q5~g9kL89VYp3SgQTWvQ4escBt66o7vo7-lo6mEHcEU2PRLr70yT8iXzmRDSxmLD-lNCca5XWhu0brcWGtPAe2NZoY~c26OnPNK3UZ9qGUy29vAE8kz7i-w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net:443 [d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.33.76.95, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.33.76.191, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.33.76.121, d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/13.33.76.54] failed: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:89)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 69 more
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720035/gradle-%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/889541#889541

Comment: Оперативной памяти 16Гб

Comment: upps, я вот это имел ввиду https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940359/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-andoid-studio-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5/1035601#1035601

Answer (score 0):

У вас в логах вот ключевые строки:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0)
```

Во-первых попробуйте синхронизировать с файловой системой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же возможно у вас градл работает в оффлайн режиме и соответственно если все установлено начисто то никакого кеша нету, отключите оффлайн режим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-could-not-get-resource-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-gradle-3-1-0-gradle-3-1-0-pom/26734/4) обсуждение данной проблемы. Так же [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f) первоисточник данного ответа. Может поможет [ссылка_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129176/org-gradle-api-projectconfigurationexception-a-problem-occurred-configuring-pro), [ссылка_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801157/how-to-fix-gradle-build-error-a-problem-occurred-configuring-root-project), [ссылка_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode).

### UPDATE

Так же можно попробовать установить прокси для соединения в `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[PORT, TYPICALLY 3128]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[IP ADDRESS]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[PASSWORD]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[PORT, TYPICALLY 3128]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[USERNAME]
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330895/gradle-sync-failed-connection-refused) первоисточник

Comment: все это уже перепробовал. не работает.

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик, обновил ответ, попробуйте добавить прокси, может поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось проблема в роутере (Xiaomi 3g прошивка Padavan). Подключил компьютер на прямую к провайдеру и все ок. Буду разбираться почему через роутер не работает. Если есть идеи кидайте.